# Fuzzylite on VS 2012 does not compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, fuzzy-logic

I want use fuzzylite in VS 2012.
I followed the same step as given in below link :
[Using fuzzylite in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339500/using-fuzzylite-in-visual-studio-2010)

but it gives error.
Error - " No object file generated"

Using Cmake to compile source code of fuzzylite, it generates sln files properly. But after compiling the solution it gives error. I'm blocked because of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to post your problems with fuzzylite in the forums at http://www.fuzzylite.com, where I and others keep track of them and we are very happy to help you.

I believe the error you are finding is due to warning C4702 being raised during compile time. 
This is happening in fuzzylite v.4.0, and a solution is to add in file `fl/fuzzylite.h` the following line within the `#ifdef FL_WINDOWS` (together with the other `#pragma`s):

`#pragma warning(disable:4702) //Ignore unreachable code`

For future reference, please refer to the forums at http://www.fuzzylite.com

Comment: thanks for information .. from now onwards.. will post of given link